# XSLT 1.0 Preliminary processing strategy

Tags: xslt

(Let me risk a general strategy question that might offend protocol and embarrass me.)

Before the element-by-element transformation of my input XML into HTML, I need to determine the order in which elements will be presented. Doing so requires recursive analyses, including merging ordered lists and tracing a graph, all based on attributes of the elements to be presented.

After that processing I have, in effect, an ordered list of attribute values, and I will present the elements sorted by that list.

Which strategy is better?

1) Put the results of the pre-analysis into a global variable, which would be a list of attribute values, and then iterate through that list, something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name=orderOfPresentation>
    <xsl:call-template name="analyses">
</xsl:variable>


<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="$orderOfPresentation">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

or

2) Apply formatting templates deep in the analyses, once the ordered list has been determined, without closing out the recursions, something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:call-template name="analysis">
        [with, as parameters, various sets of attribute nodes, extracted from the input XML]
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="analysis">
    [recursions that include calls to sub-analysis]
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sub-analysis">
    [recursions that include calls to sub-sub-analysis]]
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sub-sub-analysis">
    [more work, which eventually produces an ordered list, $orderOfPresentation]
    <xsl:for-each select="$orderOfPresentation">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The first strategy may just expose the thinking of a procedural-language programmer but does seem to have the benefit of letting the processor clean up after itself before getting on with the business of the real transformation.

But XLST 1.0 (in which I must work, without extensions) doesn't have a simple way to represent a list of string values, and (if I understand this correctly) can only pass back to the global variable a Result Tree Fragment (something I fail to understand). So strategy (1) seems bad.

But (2), a strategy that calls all the real transformation from deep inside a recursion, seems inefficient and difficult to maintain.

Is one of these strategies the best practice? Or are they both evidence of a confused mind?

Comment: How does the environment look where your XSLT processor is called from? Is there a chance to apply a first XSLT program for sorting, store the resulting XML somewhere and process this through a second XSLT program which does the "XML to HTML" conversion? This is what I would try here.

Comment: The conversion is being done client-side, in the web browser. So, no I can't store intermediate XML.

Comment: Well, I don't know much about JavaScript, but isn't it possible to do what I suggested by using JavaScript? This example http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp looks like it could be modified easily to run the XSLT processor twice.

Comment: I know Javascript much better than I know XSLT! I've been plenty tempted on this project to say, "Oh, this functional XSLT is too unfamiliar. Let me kick out into Javascript and work there." But at least so far, every time I've resisted the urge, I've been pleased with the final result. So I'm still pushing myself to stay in XSLT.

Comment: What I suggested was not to *replace* your XSLT by Javascript, just to use JavaScript to run 2 XSLT programs one after another. Since XSLT 1.0 is only well-suited for doing *one* transformation, not two, to keep everything in one XSLT script may not please you this time.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't be so afraid of passing a list of strings back up to a global variable. An RTF can be a string (or made into one, I think) and I could make my "list of strings" just one long delimited string (delimited with tabs?) and then write a split routine to feed the for-each loop. Hmm.

Comment: @JPM: I recommend the 1st strategy -- you just have to use the xxx:node-set extension function to convert the RTF to a normal tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The needed result of the pre-processing is a list of strings (an ordered list of attribute values), so:

Ignore the fact that an RTF is a tree fragment and just treat it like a string. In the called template, don't create XML nodes, just output strings using value-of plus a delimiter.

The global variable becomes effectively just a list of strings. (The functions `substring-before( , delimiter)` and `substring-after( , delimiter)` can form a nice little pop function for the list.)

So get the benefits of finishing the preprocessing first (strategy 1) instead of launching the transformation from deep inside the preprocessing (strategy 2), but do so by thinking of the global variable not as an RTF but as an ordered list of strings.

Comment: I couldn't rely on a node-set() extension since this is client-side transformation in a browser. I want to avoid the Javascript to make the style sheet easy for others to use, adapt and maintain. The strategy here is lightweight and working well so far.

Answer (score 1):

Like Doc Brown, I would use a third strategy: generate the target stylesheet, then execute it. It's quite possible to do this in the browser with a bit of Javascript.